# Add form to html tabel cell

Tags: html

I want to add an input form to an HTML table cell when a checkbox is selected.

When I add some form of text field or number field to the table cell to create a form, the text box doesn't show. only the text of my label shows.

```
<td>
<label class="collapsible">
<input type="checkbox" />
<span class="collapser">Edit</span>
<span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
<div class="collapsed">
<form method="post">
<label for="pwd">Hello World</label><br>
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" id="pwd" name=min_qty>
</form></div></label></td>
```

My Css code as well:

```
.collapsible {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.collapsible input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.collapsible input:focus ~ .collapser {
  border-color: grey;
}
.collapsible .collapser {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px transparent dotted;

}

.collapsible .arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}
.collapsible input:checked ~ .arrow,
.collapsible input:checked ~ .collapser .arrow {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.collapsible .collapsed {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* fade out, then shrink */
  transition: opacity 0.25s, margin 0.5s 0.25s, font-size 0.5s 0.25s, padding 0.5s 0.25s;
}
.collapsible input:checked ~ .collapsed {
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* grow, then fade in */
  transition: margin 0.25s, padding 0.25s, font-size 0.25s, opacity 0.5s 0.25s;
}
```

[My table output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kl6q.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

My CSS was affecting all of my inputs, not just my check boxes.

Changed this:

```
}
.collapsible input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

to this:

```
.collapsible input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```